# Link 3d objects in Three.js

Tags: three.js, pivot, parent

I need to move several planes link each other like in the image to compose different configurations. Is it possible only with "child" "parent" mesh relation or there is a better way?

Here is  an image that explain all:[image: http://www.studiogusto.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/threeJSlinkedplanes.png]

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible only with "child" "parent" mesh relation or there is a better way?

Child/parent mesh relation should do the trick yep.